# Understanding oracle SCN

Tags: oracle

I am currently working as junior Oracle DBA in a company.Now my team leads always tell me that I have to understand how SCN works and what I can do with the knowledge about SCN.So,are they really correct?
I know SCN is system change number and a little more something about SCN but where can I find the exhaustive documentation and practice material related to SCN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [**Glossary from the Oracle Documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/glossary.htm#CNCPT2120)

> System Change Number. A database ordering primitive. The value of an SCN is the logical point in time at which changes are made to a database.

There is lots of info you can easily Google

- http://oracledbascriptsfromajith.blogspot.com/2009/05/understanding-scnsystem-change-number.html
- http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/scn.html

Even the DBA StackExchange already has questions around the SCN

- [How do I find my current SCN?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11405/how-do-i-find-my-current-scn)
- [RMAN-06054: media recovery requesting unknown archived log, Where is SCN kept?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7498/rman-06054-media-recovery-requesting-unknown-archived-log-where-is-scn-kept)
- [Commit vs Fast Commit vs Commit Cleanout in Oracle Database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25529/commit-vs-fast-commit-vs-commit-cleanout-in-oracle-database/25530#25530)
- [more...](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Boracle%5D%20scn)

Answer (score 1):

The best source for Oracle internals is generally the Oracle Concepts Guide.

In this case they have a pretty good description, including how it works as part of transaction control.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/transact.htm#CNCPT039

Comment: Nothing beats the Docs. +1 !!!